# Grouped bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart with data in long form.

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(group = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group1", 
"group2", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group4", "group1", "group4", 
"group4", "group1", "group4", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group1", 
"group4", "group2", "group4", "group2", "group3", "group3", "group1", 
"group1", "group3", "group3", "group1", "group1", "group3", "group1", 
"group4", "group3", "group3", "group1", "group2", "group1", "group4", 
"group1", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group2", "group2", "group4", 
"group3", "group3", "group3", "group2", "group3", "group2", "group1", 
"group1", "group3", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group4", "group1", 
"group4", "group1", "group1", "group4", "group1", "group3", "group4", 
"group1", "group4", "group2", "group4", "group1", "group2", "group4", 
"group1", "group4", "group1", "group2", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group2", "group1", "group3", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group3", "group4", "group1", "group3", "group1", "group3", "group4", 
"group1", "group2", "group1", "group3", "group1"), category = c("category4", 
"category5", "category2", "category4", "category3", "category6", 
"category3", "category1", "category4", "category2", "category6", 
"category6", "category5", "category5", "category4", "category4", 
"category1", "category6", "category1", "category4", "category6", 
"category6", "category2", "category6", "category3", "category2", 
"category6", "category3", "category6", "category1", "category6", 
"category2", "category2", "category2", "category5", "category1", 
"category1", "category4", "category3", "category4", "category4", 
"category5", "category1", "category3", "category5", "category2", 
"category2", "category5", "category5", "category2", "category6", 
"category6", "category5", "category1", "category4", "category3", 
"category6", "category1", "category6", "category3", "category2", 
"category2", "category3", "category2", "category2", "category5", 
"category4", "category4", "category4", "category4", "category1", 
"category5", "category6", "category5", "category4", "category5", 
"category1", "category2", "category3", "category5", "category3", 
"category2", "category4", "category6", "category4", "category6", 
"category1", "category4", "category4", "category3", "category4", 
"category5", "category5", "category6", "category4", "category3", 
"category5", "category3", "category3", "category1"), count = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I run the following:

```
pivot_sample %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=group,fill=category))+
  geom_bar()
```

[image]
The `stat_count()` default function seems to work just fine with the default `position="stack"`
However, when I switch to `position="dodge"` in the code below:

```
pivot_sample %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=group,y=count,fill=category))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity")
```

[image]
It won't count the `count` variable.

I am sure there is something basic I am missing and could use another perspective.
Do I need to use a `count` function for the `y=` argument in the `aes()`?

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the first one, you are not using the 'count' column.  So, it does a count which would be similar to `pivot_sample %>% %>% ggplot(aes(x = group, fill = category)) +  geom_bar(position = "dodge")` `stat= 'identity'` uses the exact values from that column 'count' instead of aggregation

Comment: @akrun, That's a good point. I was trying to plot with the data in this format to make it easier for looping through plots, but it seems like it may be a better idea to loop through the variables to create a list of summary tables that can be plotted rather than try using operations on a count variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, the simple answer here is just to add `position="dodge"` to your original plot code and it works fine to separate the bars according to the group aesthetic (which is not specified, so it will default for the bar geom to use the `fill` aesthetic as the one to group by):

```
pivot_sample %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=group, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge')
```

[image]

The reason is that the default option for the `stat` argument in `geom_bar` is `stat="count"`.  This will count all the observations and plot along the y axis the "count".  To access this you can use the `..` notation:  `..count..`, but it's not necessary with `geom_bar()`.  So, the code below shows you kind of a long form that shows you the same plot:

```
pivot_sample %>%
ggplot(aes(x=group, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', aes(y=..count..), stat="count")
```

Note that your data frame has a column called "count", but `pivot_sample$count` is not what is accessed when you specify and use `..count..`.  What's being accessed there is the result after the `stat="count"` function is run.

What happened when you used `stat="identity"`?  Well, the `"identity"` stat plots the actual value on the y axis.  You specified `y=count`, which means that the value of the column `pivot_sample$count` was plotted at each grouping and category.  `geom_bar` with `stat="identity"` is the same as using `geom_col()` (which should be used in that case), which will require `x` and `y` aesthetics to be defined.  In this case, the "identity" will result in adding up all the values of the y aesthetic - or `pivot_sample$count`.

In your plot you showed using `stat="identity"`, you are seeing the value of `count` represented as the bar height equal to the sum of all values of `pivot_sample$count` for each bar.  You don't have a lot of values = 1 for that column in the data, so that's why it looks the way it does.

Note that `geom_bar()` using `stat="count"` counts *observations*, whereas `stat="identity"` totals the *value*.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies a lot. What I realized after reading your post is that my example above is a sample of 100 observations from the larger dataset that I anonymized. Adding `position="dodge,"` like you said, counts the category column. But I am looking for the count described in your last paragraph.

However, I am still confused on the last paragraph. Why is the Y axis the range of possible values (i.e. 0-1) rather than setting a limit similar at the top end of the range of the sum of values in the count column? Do I need to set the Y-axis range myself?

Comment: can you clarify my last question regarding the y-axis scale?

Comment: If you want to show `pivot_sample$count` on the y axis, use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()`.  Regardless, the reason you have only 0 to 1 is because the data you supplied only has ranges of 0 or 1 for any value of `pivot_sample$count` of the grouping of category/group column.  If your full dataset has different values, you would see that.  If you want to add up groupings, then you may want to use `stat_summary()`.